# Shortcode not working properly

Tags: html, css, wordpress, function, shortcode

The shortcode i have created is not working properly anymore. Yesterday it was working fine i managed to use it.

Basically the shortcode i have created is lightbox javascript wherein if you click a thumbnail it will become bigger.

Here is an image of the problem

http://i255.photobucket.com/albums/hh140/testament1234/broken_zps2bdc406b.jpg

Here is a link to the page

http://chrisadebahr.com/my-beautiful-family/

Basically on mozilla is shows a grey box container, while on google chrome and IE it shows a broken image icon.

I'm positive the shortcode was working properly yesterday when i tested it. Not sure if it has something to do with wordpress

**FUNCTIONS.PHP**

Here is the code in my functions.php

```
//Gallery Shortcode 2
function short_gallery($atts, $content = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(), $atts));
return '<div class=" gallery_box"><div class="inner_gallery"><a class="fancybox" href="'.$content.'"><img src="'.$content.'"/></a></div></div>';
}
add_shortcode("gallery", "short_gallery");
```

**CSS**

Here is the code in my styling.

```
/*GALLERY SHORTCODE STYLES*/
.gallery_box{background-color:#E8ECEF; float:left; margin:0px 20px 20px 0px; width:250px; height:200px; overflow:hidden; border:5px solid #E8ECEF;  }
.inner_gallery img{max-width : 370px; max-height : 370px;}
```

The shortcode is easy to use. For example

```
[Gallery]http://chrisadebahr.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/ESL-Heat.jpg[gallery]
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind i managed to eliminate the error. The problem was that the user made some spaces in the shortcode. Kinda irritating to be honest. A simple space made a huge problem. For example

```
[gallery]     url     [/gallery]
```

In order for it to work properly it has to be

```
[gallery]url[/gallery].
```

No spaces in the short code. My next question is how can i eliminate this kind of problem wherein the user accidentally made some spaces in the shortcode